# Can anyone suggest an open-source real-time network stack?

Tags: c, networking, embedded

I need to integrate a network stack into my embedded application. It can be a cross-platform real-time network stack written on C. The application is based on ARM7 processor and FreeRTOS kernel.

For example I would use TRECK (Treck Inc.) or Fusion (Unicoi Systems) real-time network stacks if they were free. Also I know that, for instance, there are ports of FreeBSD's and OpenBSD's network stacks to eCos operating systems, but is it possible to obtain them as a stand-alone package so that it's relatively easy to integrate them? Although I suspect they are not real-time.

Please, do not suggest me to change the OS for my application to one that has a built-in network stack. :-)

Comment: what is your definition of real-time?  and how do you expect to have a real-time network stack that is independent of the operating system?

Comment: @dwelch A RT function is a function with predictable time of execution. In respect to a network stack this can be applied to its internal logic (external messages obviously come unpredictably). Of course if you try to launch a RT stack on non-RT OS then the total effect of the stack services will be non-RT.

Comment: you are assuming an rt stack on a foreign rt os will be deterministic?

Comment: @dwelch Well, why not? Take for instance Net+OS RT OS (by Digi). It consists of ThreadX real-time kernel and TRECK real-time stack. But I concede that one can embed a RT stack into a RT OS so unskilfully that the result will not be deterministic. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Why, I've found at least uIP and lwIP open-source network stacks. But they appear to be not real-time.

Comment: TCP/IP itself is not "real-time" (in the sense that it is non-deterministic), so perhaps that does not matter.  Generally what you need to do is to integrate the stack in such a way that stack operations do not interfere with the real-time critical parts of your system.  This normally involves running the stack in a low priority task and feeding it via a buffer, pipe, or queue for example.